# How to list the file path while using grep?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, grep

So, I'm using

```
imhead ../rawdata/m13/m13_dark/*.fit | grep 'Dark Frame'
```

*imhead* basically prints the header of the FITS files(FITS is one of the major image files used in astronomy). Think of it as *exif* for photography files. So, I'm running it through all the .fits files in the directory and I get the output

```
IMAGETYP= 'Dark Frame' /        Type of image
IMAGETYP= 'Dark Frame' /        Type of image
IMAGETYP= 'Dark Frame' /        Type of image
IMAGETYP= 'Dark Frame' /        Type of image
IMAGETYP= 'Dark Frame' /        Type of image
```

Which is expected because I know that there are only 5 files in this directory whose headers contain the string 'Dark Frame'

I want to print the file paths of these files in which grep finds the string 'dark frame'.

How do I go about it? Is there another command that I should be using along with *grep* for that.

`grep -l` or `grep -H` do not seem to work

Here is a typical output of the imhead command run on a single file
[Imhead Output](https://pastebin.com/dvigWP2H)

Comment: can you add example headers of fit files and what output you need? if you are going to pass just text input to `grep` how do you expect it to know which file it came from?

Comment: since your edit still doesn't answer my queries.. perhaps, you should loop over files one by one... untested, but something like `for file in ../rawdata/m13/m13_dark/*.fit; do grep -q 'Dark Frame' <(imhead "$file") && echo "$file"; done`

Comment: This is a normal imhead output for one fits file. 
  https://pastebin.com/dvigWP2H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to use** `imhead`

Now that I understand what you are doing a bit more, the approach mentioned in the comment about using `find` and a short helper script (say `chkDarkFrame.sh`) should provide a solution. For example, you can pass each `*.fit` file found in your `../rawdata/m13/m13_dark/` directory to `chkDarkFrame.sh` using a call to `find` similar to:

```
find ../rawdata/m13/m13_dark/ -type f -name "*.fit" -exec ./chkDarkFrame.sh '{}' \;
```

(**note:** you can limit whether `find` checks resursively with the `-maxdepth` option)

Your `chkDarkFrame.sh` helper script could call `imhead` on the filename and pipe the result to `grep -q` and if `'Dark Frame'` is present in the `imhead` output, print the filename, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
imhead "$1" | grep -q 'Dark Frame' && printf "%s\n" "$1"
```

Give that a try and let me know if that is closer. Sorry for the early confusion.

Comment: instead of so many commands, just use `grep -l`... but the issue is input files are not text files but images..

Comment: Actually this won't work if I don't use the imhead command (grep could work with the fits file directly but the files are huge and it would take a humongous amount of time). Also grep -H returns 'Standard input'

Comment: @Prathamesh did you try the for-loop I suggested?

Comment: The loop works, but I was wondering if there's a simpler method(without using a loop). Maybe using another command.

Grep -l or -H only return standard input

Comment: I understand you must use `imhead`. Then `find` with an `-execdir` launching a helper that calls `imhead` may be the ticket.